# Different references to the same library in two versions of a project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have two versions of same project. Both have a reference to the same DLL, but at different locations.

The first `csproj` includes:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Expression.Effects, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\..\3rdParty\Microsoft\Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The second `csproj`, which uses a NuGet package, includes:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Expression.Effects, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\..\..\3rdParty\NuGet\packages\Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I try to understand the reason for that. Can I use the same hint path for them? Which to choose?

Comment: Did you add the references yourself in both projects? Where does the DLL in `..\..\..\3rdParty\Microsoft\Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll` come from?

Comment: @thatguy -someone alse added references (he dosn`t work with us any more) I just want the understand the reason why there are 2 copies. I have no idea where from ..\..\..\3rdParty\Microsoft\Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll was taken. how can i know that? what are the advatehes of taken from nuget?

Comment: In your second example, is there a NuGet package installed to the project?

Comment: @thatguy - i don`t know i`ll check that. can you explain please what is the difference between installed and uninstall (but used) package. and in general how should i approach the dll duplicated use as here?

Comment: @thatguy-yes in second example NuGet package is installed

Comment: The `hintpath` can be modified manually.The second situation is the nuget right behavior initially when you install the nuget package. It uses the packages folder's path which is copied by nuget from the global nuget caches.

Comment: And for the first situation, I think someone simply copies the corresponding DLL path from the `packages` folder to a folder in the project and change the `HintPath` to refer to the path. This behavior is completely fine, after all, hintPath will be fine as long as it finds the corresponding DLL and the behavior can reduce the path length of the DLL so that it prevents the computer from being unable to recognize long addresses.

Comment: @Yakov, you can change the hintpath to use the same for them. Just make sure you find the correct DLL path. If `thatguy's` answer helps you understand this issue, `please do not forget to mark it and if not, please feel free to let us know`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Project

The `Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll` was copied to the `..\..\..\3rdParty\Microsoft\` directory manually and then referenced in Visual Studio by e.g. *right-click* on the project then *Add > Reference... > Browse...* and selecting the DLL in the corresponding directory.

Your former co-worker most likely copied the library from the local installation folder of the Expression Blend SDK (*or somewhere else*) to a folder in the solution, so that it is always available. Otherwise the library would be referenced from the local installation folder and everbody working on the project would have to install the SDK to the same location or else the reference would not be found.

### Second Project

In the second case a NuGet package was installed to the project via `packages.config`. This is just one mechanism to manage packages in your project that stores the information about referenced packages in a file called `packages.config` in your project. To install a package, *right-click* the project and choose *Manage NuGet Packages...*. In the tab *Installed*, you will see that you use the `Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend` package.

A package can contain a variety of different artifcats like DLLs. The power of packages is that you can manage dependencies much  more conveniently than with the common way of referencing DLLs like in the first project. When you install a package, the contained libraries will automatically be referenced in your project file. You **do not** add or modify these references yourself, the package manager does that for you. Let's have a look at the `HintPath`.

- `..\..\..\3rdParty\NuGet\packages\` is the root path where the packages are installed and extracted
- `Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend.1.0.0\` is the root of the concrete package in version `1.0.0`
- `lib\net45\` is the package internal path for libraries for .NET Framework >= 4.5

> Can I use same hint path for them? Which to choose?

As you can see, the question is more like whether you should use NuGet packages or reference libraries manually. This depends on the requirements of you project. In general, I recommend to use NuGet packages, since they make it much easier to manage dependencies. However, if there is no package for the library you need, you will have to add references yourself.